# How to prevent to run multiple times when click multiple times on one custom button

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button, jquery

I have one custom button. When i click on that button, That will send an email. But some times it sending multiple emails because if i click on that custom button multiple times at a time.

Comment: onclick of button use javascript and hide that button

Comment: One option is disabling the button once you clicked, until the response come from backend

Comment: check this out: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/doublesubmit/

Comment: I have done something like this earlier: onClick="this.style.display = 'none';"